# What iOS / iphone app can give me turn by turn navigation of a pre-planned route?

Tags: maps, planning, navigation

What iOS / iphone app can provide turn by turn navigation of a pre-planned (mostly on road) route (stored in GPX or TCX file)?  Voice features are nice, but not mandatory. I've found many apps that will track my ride, or display a route and my position, but none that will direct me when to turn to follow the planned route.  This would be very useful when training for an event where gpx files have been provided, or exploring new routes that I plan to ride in unfamiliar territory.

I'm ideally looking for something like the android [cue sheet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matrangola.cuesheet.ui) app.

Comment: FWIW, I tend to plan my rides with RideWithGps - http://ridewithgps.com/

Comment: Are you not wanting to use Apple Maps or Google Maps?

Comment: Apple Maps and Google maps are great, but don't provide the level of detail to follow a complicated route based on a GPX or TCX file, like a 100k loop in to the countryside that starts and ends at my house. This wouldn't really be used to find out how to get somewhere, but more to prompt me to follow a route I've already planned, as an alternative to a paper cue sheet.

Comment: Keep an eye out for bikecityguide (http://bikecityguide.org) - they were working on the import GPX track feature in February (I don't know if it's available yet)

Comment: The strava app still does NOT have this feature as of December 2015.  If it did, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also consider Co-Rider (
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/co-rider/id538095358?mt=8).

I have used it for turn-by-turn successfully and it does allow for GPX import although I can't confirm that you'll find both features working together.

Good luck.

Comment: Looks like there are no street names in directions when uploading gpx file.  I'm guessing tcx import would be more helpful since it includes custom cue sheet hints, unfortunately this doesn't support the tcx import.

Comment: July 26 update includes the feature to "import TCX files which can hold a cue sheet for improved guidance.." so perhaps that's more helpful for you.

Comment: TCX file import works well with co-rider.  I was able to view cue sheet information from a ride created in mapmyride with custom cue sheet hints and all.

Comment: This app now integrates with ridewithgps website, and that makes it really useful, since it makes loading routes very quick and easy. However, I'm switching over to RideWithGps's own app going forward.

Answer (score 2):

The RideWithGPS Android and iPhone apps now also offers this with subscription payment.

http://ridewithgps.com/app

As mentioned before, the RideWithGPS website is useful for trip planning, you can customize your cue sheets, save maps and route for offline use, etc.

Comment: This is my favorite service, and the app is really good. Now you can even use the RWGPS app with a Wahoo RFLKT to get turn by turn directions without having your phone on the bars.

Comment: Ride with gps! Finally. New iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

Try wikiloc.com. You can download routes from others and follow them. Me and my friend have used it with great success. It is notturn by turn like a car's gps would be, instead it draws a line over a map that marks the route to be followed, a dot that marks your current position and another line in another colour that traces your actual path. The map spins according to your travelling direction at the last few seconds, such as if the line-to-be-followed turns to the right it means you actually have to turn to the right.The app is designed to record trails in several sports from cycling to motoring, an after you upload a trail you can see it from a normal ween browser for a bigger map and elevation diagrams.

Comment: There is a similar app to this called Memory Map. Shows a (gpx) route and a current position, but doesn't do turn-by-turn. The upside to this app is the top-quality mapping (certainly of the UK/Europe - in the UK you can view electronic versions of the OS maps, similar France and IGN), the downside is the cost (these maps are "official" and therefore copyrighted). An app like this running off OSM would be a killer.